# Inno Setup doesn't update value in [INI]

Tags: inno-setup, ini

I'm revising script in Inno Setup Compiler 6.2.1 and got into a strange behavior.

In `[INI]` section I've got the following entry:

```
Filename: "{code:GetIniPath}\REHEV.INI"; Section: "WIDTH"; Key: "MIS_RISHUI"; \
    String: "10"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
```

When I run the installer, the log sees that file but tells that

> Skipping updating the .INI file, only updating uninstall log.

However, if I change the `Key` to `MISRISHUI` (the same text but without an underscore) the update works.

How can I deal with underscore?
I've got quite a few keys like this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. Underscore or not.

Isn't the problem the [`createkeyifdoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=inisection&anchor=createkeyifdoesntexist)? It means that if your INI file already contains the `MIS_RISHUI` key, it won't be updated. While if you remove the underscore, you are effectively writing a new key, which does not exist yet in the INI file.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with this flag. Somehow I was sure this flag checks if key exists and if yes then updates it and if doesn't exists then creates it. Now I understand it only creates